# How to add to Shopify site on different host

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain, shopify

My friend has a website with Shopify. She wants some changes to her website which will entail me adding a database and some web pages. We can't have very technical conversations so from my research I have deduced that she has a domain but no hosting as Shopify host everything. So how do I work this out?

I need a host which will be different from the host serving Shopify I gather. So do I need something like a subdomain? If she gets a host for me will she need to create the subdomain in Shopify? How does it all work with Shopify and adding non-shopify stuff to a website?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use a subdomain e.g. `shop.example.com` and in DNS point the A Record for that subdomain to the IP address supplied by shopify.

Then the regular website will be at `example.com` and it should have a link to `shop.example.com` which will be the shopify shop.

Comment: To expand on this answer - When you have the subdomain (eg shop.example.com) pointed to Shopify you need to add this information in Shopify as well so it can associate the shopify site with your subdomain.

Comment: You could point `www.example.com` to Shopify and point `blog.example.com` to your other host if you wanted to make your store the main focal point of your site.    The shop doesn't have to be the one on the subdomain.

Comment: I appreciate this everyone! I shall endeavour to do this and choose this answer when I've got it sorted.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes indeedy...thanks for pointing that out.